# Terminal program: unable to find the directory/file though they are in the correct pathway

Tags: shell, version-control, diff, patch

What else could be going wrong? Sorry I'm pretty new to programming so I'm not sure if this is the proper way to frame my question.

[image: screenshot]

Here is the code from the terminal file:

```
echo "Patcher Coded by _Retro_"
PLACE=`dirname $0`
ROM=`ls ${PLACE}/Rom/*.nds | head -n 1`
PATCH=`ls ${PLACE}/Patch/*.* | head -n 1`
NAME=${ROM%.[^.]*}

$PLACE/xdelta3 -dfs $ROM $PATCH $NAME-patched.nds
```

Comment: There are many things wrong in your script; what are you setting as `$0`?

Comment: Don't post a screenshot of text. Just copy the text and paste it (as code) into your question.

Answer (score 0):

Your script says this:

> ```
> PLACE=`dirname $0`
> ```

First, the shell performs parameter expansion. That means (in this case) it expands `$0`. The variable `$0` expands to the path used by the shell to execute your script, so that line expands to this:

```
PLACE=`dirname /Users/ShakeyBanks/Desktop/Perfect Heart CE./DS_Rom_Patcher/Rom_Patcher`
```

Note that there are no backslashes in the expansion! The backslashes were consumed by your interactive shell before starting the script.

Then the shell performs command substitution: it executes the command enclosed in `` `...` ``. The shell splits the command on spaces, so the command contains four words. The first word is the program to run, and the remaining three words are arguments to that command:

1. `dirname`
2. `/Users/ShakeyBanks/Desktop/Perfect`
3. `Heart`
4. `CE./DS_Rom_Patcher/Rom_Patcher`

The problem here is that the `dirname` program only wants **one** argument, but you're passing it three. It detects this and fails with an error:

> ```
> usage: dirname path
> ```

To fix this, quote the `$0` with double-quotes, like this:

```
PLACE=`dirname "$0"`
```

You also need to quote all subsequent uses of `$PLACE`, `${PLACE}`, `$ROM`, `$PATCH`, and `$NAME` with double-quotes, because they will have the same problem.

**OR**, rename your directory to not contain spaces.